# Cant enable checkout without a PayPal account

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have setup a woocommerce on website with Paypal chekout. The Paypal account is Business and settings are changed to "Paypal Account Optional" - on.

But the checkout still forces to create Paypal account without simple credit card checkout. Why?? What could be possible wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using my [PayPal for WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) extension, by chance, or are you using the built in PayPal, or what exactly?

Comment: @Andrew-Angell I'm using standard Woocommerce build in checkout option - PayPal standard (just entering Paypal email).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the merchant account email address is confirmed.

Comment: There is SSL certificate installed on the site. Should I change the encrypted website payments to on?

Answer (score 1):

When using Payments Standard it's all based on browser session cookies.  If you've signed in to a PayPal account with that browser it assumes that's what you'll be doing in the future so it hides the guest checkout option a little more.

If you clear the browser cache/cookies, or use a fresh browser, you should see the guest checkout option more prominently displayed during checkout.

Express Checkout handles this a little better where rather than completely working from cookies you can make adjustments in your API calls.  The [PayPal for WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) plugin provides Express Checkout so you could utilize this benefit.  There are options in the plugin settings to adjust that accordingly.

It still looks a little different depending on your browser cache/cookies and the version of PayPal they've got you on, but in general the guest checkout (credit card) option is much more obvious to people when using Express Checkout with those options enabled.